# Is there a way to send a SharePoint survey out like new multiple times?

Tags: survey

I built a survey in SharePoint 2010 that pulls data from Service Manager (Date, IncidentID, and Analyst) for a customer satisfaction survey.  The survey auto sends each time a ticket (IR or SR) is closed.  My problem is if do not set allow multiple responses to yes, the user gets an error the second time they try to complete the survey.  By allowing multiple responses, I will show several hundred responses in a matter of weeks and have to export and filter to get weekly, monthly, or individual technician results.

My question is, because the Incident ID is pulled directly from Service Manager and is independent each time, is there a way to send out the same survey each time a ticket is closed, but show individual results instead of grouped together and only allow one response per survey?